# Powershell, list the amount of printers from a server

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get all printers from a server as a number (count) so far i managed to make this:

```
$env = 'localhost'
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $env
```

Which is listing all the printing and the propierties, I don't need the info of the printers, the only i need is to count how much printers (in total) that server is hosting.

I can't manage to make the script to do that, thank you in advance.

Comment: `(Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $env).Count`

Comment: TIMTOWDI: `Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $env | Measure-Object`

Comment: `GWMI Win32_Printer | FT local, network, shared, portname, name -Au` could show a difference between _installed_ and _hosted_  printers. You might be going to discriminate between them?